# Convex functions gradient

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

We have a convex differentiable function which is defined in the open convex set. How to prove that the gradient of that function is continuous.

Comment: I answered that question here.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3793230/gradient-of-a-convex-function-is-continuous-on-the-interior-of-its-domain/3793318#3793318